# Sed, extract lines from text

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I really would like to know how can I extrac some line from a text file using sed, but I'd like to extract the lines at interval:

For example extract the line with number i=1:2:100

So that i can extrac the lines 1,3,5... and so on until 100

I haven't been able to find a solution by myself trying with sed command  and on the web i didn't found anything

I know that probably there's a better way using python but I'm not very acquainted with it!!!
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require a lot of manual work in pure sed but Bash can help you.

```
sed -n $(for i in {1..100..2}; do echo -n " -e ${i}p"; done)
```

### Explanation

In sed, you can print a line specified by its number by using the [`p` command](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-31) after the line number, e.g. `1p` prints the first line of a file. To disable printing other lines, add the `-n` option.

If you need to specify multiple lines, i.e. [multiple sed expressions](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-13), you have to use `-e` before every expression.

So for lines 1, 3, 5, the result is:

```
sed -n -e 1p -e 3p -e 5p
```

#### Generating the list of line numbers

However, it would be pretty exhausting to list all odd numbers less than 100 manually. You can use Bash to generate the list.

The command [`echo {1..100..2}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273087/711006) generates the list of all odd numbers less than 100. And you can use the `for` command to put the numbers into the required surrounds:

```
$ for i in {1..100..2}; do echo -n " -e ${i}p"; done
 -e 1p -e 3p -e 5p -e 7p -e 9p -e 11p -e 13p -e 15p -e 17p -e 19p -e 21p -e 23p -e 25p -e 27p -e 29p -e 31p -e 33p -e 35p -e 37p -e 39p -e 41p -e 43p -e 45p -e 47p -e 49p -e 51p -e 53p -e 55p -e 57p -e 59p -e 61p -e 63p -e 65p -e 67p -e 69p -e 71p -e 73p -e 75p -e 77p -e 79p -e 81p -e 83p -e 85p -e 87p -e 89p -e 91p -e 93p -e 95p -e 97p -e 99p
```

To include the result of this `for` command into another command, use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html): `$(command)`

### Passing the input to sed

If you want to pass a file to sed, provide it as the last parameter. Otherwise, sed expects the output to be in [stdin](https://www.howtogeek.com/435903/what-are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-on-linux/).

### Saving the output to a file

If you want to save the output to a file, just append `> filename` to the command to redirect sed’s [stdout](https://www.howtogeek.com/435903/what-are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-on-linux/) into the file.

Comment: Wow, really useful thanks for the detailed explanation,  hope that i can redirect all these lines to a text file easily.

Comment: @Andrea Of course, just append `> filename` to redirect sed’s stdout.